# Is there a way to transfer achievements across regions?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I play in two different Battlenet regions due to my location and my World of Warcraft server and I want to keep both profiles up to date with my Starcraft 2 achievements.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save the game just before getting an achievement on one region (South East Asia) then you can load it on the America region and it will get it for you again. I did this during wings of liberty. 
When you go to load the game on the other region, click the icon under load with the 3 folders and it will open a new window like:
C:\Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\xxxxxxx\6-xxxxxxxx\Saves\Campaign
You will need to up 3 directories and pull the saves from another region (6 = SEA, 1 = Americas)

Be aware though that once they patch the game the in game saves are useless for achievements. As for multiplayer achievements you will need to get them again.

Comment: Seems like a lot of effort :P But at least it's possible.