# Campaigns on Different Servers

Tags: starcraft-2

Last night they took down the NA servers before I got a chance to play to log in. So I changed my region to EU and was able to login and begin the HOTS campaign just to get the starting feel and to see what the campaign achievements are.

When I switch my region back to US will my campaign data still be there or will I need to start over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Campaign, Achievement, Account Profile Name, Ladder Rankings, and Save Game data are all stored regionally.

Every time you change to a new region, you will be starting from scratch ([though you may be able to move local copies of your save games manually](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108433/336)).

Answer (score 4):

You will have to **start over**,switching regions requires creating a new player profile meaning your progress will be stored on new profile,and when you switch back to your other profile new progress won't be transferred back.

[Starcraft Global play FAQ](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-global-play-faq)

- "Will my profile and ladder ranking be available if I switch regions?
  No, characters, profiles, and ladder rankings will not transfer between regions. When you switch to a new region for the first time, you will be prompted to create a new profile for that region. None of your existing progress in another region will transfer."

Comment: It does await you.Edited answer a bit due the possible confusion.